# Smallest prime number not divides $n$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> For each integer $n>2$, we define $p(n)$ to be the smallest prime number that does not divide $n$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{p(n)}{n}=0.$$

My argument is: We only need to prove $$\lim_{n\to \infty,\; n\; \text{is square-free}}\frac{p(n)}{n}=0$$
since $\frac{p(n)}{n}\leq \frac{p(n)}{Rad(n)}=\frac{p(Rad(n))}{Rad(n)}$. Let $p_k$ is the $k-$th prime number, for each square-free number $p_1\dots p_{k-1}<n<p_1\dots p_{k}$, $p(n)$ must be less than $p_{k+1}$ otherwise $p_1\dots p_k|n$. So $\frac{p(n)}{n}\leq \frac{p_k}{p_1\dots p_{k-1}}$. To finish, we must prove
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{p_k}{p_1\dots p_{k-1}}=0$$
For a moment, I thought this is obvious however I couldn't prove the above limit equals $0$. How can I continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Armed with [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate), we know that $p_k\leq2p_{k-1}$, and we have
$$
\frac{p_k}{p_1\dots p_{k-1}}\leq \frac{2}{p_1\cdots p_{k-2}}
$$
and it is not difficult to see that this goes to $0$ as $k$ increases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not very elementary

Comment: Aside from a few logarithms, Erdös' proof of Bertrand's postulate lies squarely in the land of elementary number theory. So I would say it qualifies. I do agree it might be shooting mosquitoes with cannons, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can show that without Bertrand's postulate. Instead, you can use the much more elementary lemma:
$$\forall n\geq 3, \prod_{i=1}^n p_i \geq p_{n+1} + p_{n+2}$$

This can be shown by considering $p_2 \dots p_n \pm 2$. It is not divisible by any prime less than $p_n$ so it has a prime factor strictly greater than $p_n$ (because $p_2 \dots p_n \pm 2 > 1$ and it is odd so not divisible by $p_1=2$), therefore there exists $i,j>n$ such that:

$$p_2 \dots p_n + 2 \geq p_i$$
$$p_2 \dots p_n - 2 \geq p_j$$

Moreover euclid's algorithm gives
$$\gcd(p_2 \dots p_n + 2, p_2 \dots p_n - 2) = \gcd(\underbrace{p_2 \dots p_n - 2}_{\text{odd}}, 4) = 1$$
(we must use the assumption that $n\geq 3$ such that $p_2 \dots p_n - 2 > 4$)

It means that $p_2 \dots p_n + 2$ and $p_2 \dots p_n + 2$ do not share any factor. In particular, $p_i \neq p_j$ so $p_i+p_j\geq p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}$. Finally

$$\prod_{i=1}^n p_i = p_2 \dots p_n + 2 + p_2 \dots p_n - 2 \geq p_i+p_j\geq p_{n+1}+p_{n+2}$$

Plugging in your fraction gives
$$\frac{p_k}{p_1\dots p_{k-1}} \leq \frac{p_k}{(p_{k-1} + p_k)p_{k-1}}\leq \frac{1}{p_{k-1}}$$

However, $\lim_{k\to + \infty} \frac{1}{p_{k-1}}=0$, hence the desired result.